# How to create properties file inside perl script

Tags: perl

i want to create a `order.properties` and inside of order.properties file  create a variable called starttime and assign the value of current time(System time) in a YYYYMMDDHH24MM format using perl Scripting

I am a beginner to Perl scripting, please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please  show your efforts. Read the  [ask] and provide your own (even non-functioning) code, preferably in a [mcve]

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you are talking about. You will have to give us a lot more context. What's that _order.properties_ file? What date? In what format? Dates can come in all kinds of formats, like today could be `2018-12-11` or `11.12.2018` or `12/11/18` or `11th of December, 2018`. Please also note the language is called _Perl_, not _pearl_. Being accurate in your communication is very important for programming, and in general if you work with computers.

Comment: order.properties is a name of the file i want to create and date in a formate of YYYYMMDDHH:24MI and this value i want to store in a variable

Comment: thank you  - mkHun

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example `order.properties` file, and an example input information, and also what code you already have. We don't know what information you have and what output you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to create a order.properties file inside a Perl script

```
open my $fh, '>', 'order.properties' or die $!;
# Do you want to put any data into the file? Do it here
close $fh;
```

> and send the current date into the variable `$starttime`

```
use Time::Piece;

my $starttime = localtime->strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M');
```